# NoSQL DB for .NET document-based database (ECM)

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, database-design, couchdb, nosql

I'm halfway through coding a basic multi-tenant SaaS ECM solution. Each client has it's own instance of the database / datastore, but the .Net app is single instance. The documents are pretty much read only (i.e. an image archive of tiffs or PDFs)

I've used MSSQL so far, but then started thinking this might be viable in a NoSQL DB (e.g. MongoDB, CouchDB). The basic premise is that it stores documents, each with their own particular indexes. Each tenant can have multiple document types.

e.g. One tenant might have an invoice type, which has Customer ID, Invoice Number and Invoice Date. Another tenant might have an application form, which has Member Number, Application Number, Member Name, and Application Date.

So far I've used the old method which Sharepoint  (used?) to use, and created a document table which has int_field_1, int_field_2, date_field_1, date_field_2, etc. Then, I've got a "mapping" table which stores the customer specific index name, and the database field that will map to. I've avoided the key-value pair model in the DB due to volume of documents.

This way, we can support multiple document types in the one table, and get reasonably high performance out of it, and allow for custom document type searches (i.e. user selects a document type, then they're presented with a list of search fields).

However, a NoSQL DB might make this a lot simpler, as I don't need to worry about denormalizing the document. However, I've just got concerns about the rest of the data around a document. We store an "action history" against the document. This tracks views, whether someone emails the document from within the system, and other "future" functionality (e.g. faxing).

We have control over the document load process, so we can manipulate the data however it needs to be to get it in the document store (e.g. assign unique IDs). Users will not be adding in their own documents, so we shouldn't need to worry about ACID compliance, as the documents are relatively static.

So, my questions I guess :

- Is a NoSQL DB a good fit
- Is MongoDB the best for Asp.Net (I saw Raven and Velocity, but they're still kinda beta)
- Can I store a key for each document, and then store the action history in a MSSQL DB with this key? I don't need to do joins, it would be if a person clicks "View History" against a document.
- How would performance compare between the two (NoSQL DB vs denormalized "document" table)

Volumes would be up to 200,000 new documents per month for a single tenant. My current scaling plan with the SQL DB involves moving the SQL DB into a cluster when certain thresholds are reached, and then reviewing partitioning and indexing structures.

Comment: I've been told by almost everyone that once you start making dynamically generated fields in a database, you should move to a NoSQL database.. Also, note that you don't have to use NoSQL for everything, you could always do a hybrid solution.

Comment: They hybrid solution is my plan.

I'm just interested on peoples thoughts on performance, maintenance, and how I could link a hybrid solution together (e.g. assign an arbitary document ID field when documents are loaded, then use this ID field in the SQL tables? Or if I should rely on a NOSQL generated key.

Comment: I don't understand the requirements. What do you mean with "The basic premise is that it stores documents, each with their own particular indexes"? Are we talking about free text indexes or indexes on metadata? Or do you mean "metadata" when you say "index"?

Comment: Apologies for not being as clear. It's metadata (e.g. an invoice document will have an invoice number piece of metadata). It's these pieces of metadata which the users search on, and they change from client to client. I.e. one client might have an invoice document type, whereas another will have an application form document type.

Comment: You can use MongoDB gridfs for storing files and you can add metadata too. It's up to you to define what kind of metadata. I'm not sure if you can create an index on that metadata. I think you can but I have never tried. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Specification I will try.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

1. For the document oriented portions, and likely for the whole thing, a nosql solution should work fine.
2. I've played with, and heard good things about mongodb, and would probably recommend it first for a .net project.
3. For the document-oriented portion, the performance should be excellent compared to a  sql database. for smaller scale, it should be equivalent, but the ability to scale out later will be a huge benefit.